# Inserting an FPGA on a MIPI camera lane

Tags: pcb, fpga, embedded, microprocessor, ddr

I have a processor which accepts MIPI data. However, the problem is I want to perform some processing on this data and the IMX6 is not fast enough to do this in real time. I was wondering what is the best way to have the FPGA operate on the raw pixels in my image.

One of the options was getting the MIPI data into the FPGA, decod the MIPI data using a custom core(which is rather hard), and then convert it back into MIPI and send it to the IMX6 processor.(https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/applications-processors/i.mx-applications-processors/i.mx-6-processors:IMX6X_SERIES)

However, this means the FPGA has to be large to handle the MIPI logic. Is there any other way I can get the chip to communicate with my FPGA? Sharing a RAM(DDR) is rather complex and I dont want to go that way .

Is there anyway, I can have 2RAM and get the IMX6 to write image data into one RAM and then get the FPGA to read data from the RAM? If so how would I do something like this?

What is the way to get my FPGA access to image pixels without adding too much complexity?

Comment: How much complexity is too much for you? I'm voting to close this as "too broad" and completely unresearched.

Comment: Sure, anything is possible. We don't know how big your image is, how fast your processing these images or how big your ram is and how much bandwidth to the ram you have (and the clock speed). So I'll just say 'sure' for now

Answer (score 1):

Using MIPI with FPGA's seems to be a recurring question.
Xilinx have an application note which tells how you can connect a MIPI device to their chips: [Here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp894-d-phy-solutions.pdf).

As to extracting the MIPI data, I think you have to pay for their solution. But it is possible to build your own. (At least for an experienced HDL programmer).

Handling the 'MIPI stream' should not require much FPGA resources. This in contrast to image processing. A simple BTC for 8x8 blocks can easily use up most of the FPGA memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bridge chip to convert MIPI to something that the FPGA can handle without complex logic. For example [here](https://www.ti.com/product/sn65dsi84-q1) is a MIPI to LVDS bridge.
MIPI to HDMI might be another option, see [here](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADV7533.pdf)

Comment: Is that not for DSI? Would it fork for a MIPI CSI interface?

Comment: Oops didn't notice it was DSI. Probably will not work. Check out Toshiba TC358746AXBG, MIPI CSI to Parallel.